# Is there any free online tool to find best statistic distribution?

Tags: statistics, online-resources, descriptive-statistics

I have a serie of one variable data, and I want to find the best distribution that fits it.

It is a common problem, so there must be some online, but the ones I found only accept a small number of samples (I have more than 500 samples).

Do you know any good website?

Wolframalpha doesn't works for large sets (it requires payment).

Comment: Search for Rstudio

Comment: Take a random sample from your 500 samples and put that into a tool that accepts a small number of samples

Comment: Might be useful to readers if you linked to some of the ones you did find, and/or explain exactly what you did with Wolfram alpha.

Comment: R statistical software, which is free, has a Library devoted to distribution identification. I have not used it, but have been told it works well. Minitab, which is not free, but for which some universities have a sytenwide license, has a distribution ID item on the `STAT > Quality tools menu`. I have found it useful.